# NSDictionary objectForKey returns wrong value

Tags: ios, json, object, key, nsdictionary

I'm trying to use a dictionary which I got as a JSON response from my server. When I print the description of the dictionary, everything is in order

```
    Printing description of dict:
{
    category = 1;
    code = 1;
    name = "xxxx";
    pictureUrl = "xxxx";
    sessionId = xxx;
    status = 0;
}
```

I need the "code" value, and when I use objectForKey:@"code" to get it, I get a wrong value:

```
int code = [NSDictionary objectForKey:@"code"];
```

After this i print out the value of code and its something like 3483765348, which is very, very wrong.

Why is this happening?

Comment: int code = [[NSDictionary objectForKey:@"code"]int value];

try like this

Comment: @VishnuPrasath: your answer is correct and you were the first one, Never hide yourself or shy, just go on to post as an answer. If your answer is downvoted you will learn something, if upvoted then your confidence will grow, Nothing to loose here :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I actually posted first... But due to short text in answer it automatically added to comment & Thanks for your wordings..

Comment: @VishnuPrasath:  Post again, with some text in it.  I will upvote :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object returned is an NSNumber and not an int (which isn't an object).
If you want the int value try this

```
int code = [[myDictionary objectForKey:@"code"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code which will be use to solve your issue.. As per your code it returns only value you have to convert it to int value.Use this piece of code

```
int code = [[NSDictionary objectForKey:@"code"]intValue];
```

Hope this Helps !!!

Comment: My personal liking is to use NSInteger over int. And you did a typo `int Value` instead of `intValue`.

Answer (score 0):

`-objectForKey:` doesn't return an `int`, but an object instead (in your case of type `NSNumber`).

```
NSNumber *code = [myDict objectForKey:@"code"];
NSInteger codeInteger = [code integerValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int code = [[yourResultingDictionary objectForKey:@"code"] intValue];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The object key returns only for array values, so you will use value for key path.

```
user_idstr = [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"properties.user_id"];
```